# Swiftui how to use Binding in enum router

Tags: swiftui, enums, binding, navigation, router

I have a router set up like so...

```
enum TabRoute: Hashable, View {
case comments(id: String)
case followers(id: String)
case following(id: String)
case user(user: Binding<User>)

var body: some View {
    switch self {
    case .comments(let id):
        Text("Comments \(id)")
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    case .followers(let id):
        FollowersView(userId: id)
    case .following(let id):
        FollowingView(userId: id)
    case .user(var $user):
        UserView(user: $user)
    }
}
```

Which works fine when all i require is a String. However if I try to use a Binding I get 'TabRoute' does not conform to protocol Hashable or Equatable.

Any ideas on what I need to do here?

In general what I'm trying to achieve is having a reusable user detail view which I can bind to a source of truth published property in various VMs

Comment: Pass an ID for the `User` instead of a `Binding` and then have a generator function that creates the actual `Binding` based on the ID

Comment: reusable views in SwiftUI can cause problems its best to just make lots of views. and using  VM object instead of View and @State correctly will also cause problems.